# About scopes in Sublime Text 3: text.something vs source.something, and their features

Tags: sublimetext3

So I'm contributing, for the sake of learning a bit more of the innards of ST3, to a repository making a new package for Laravel's Blade templating.

In the `.sublime-syntax file`, the scope is currently set as `scope: text.blade`, which works fine except for that fact that I cannot make the autocompletion popup appear for my snippets. For that, I need to change the scope to `source.blade`. But doing to kills the ability of using `div.foo`+ `tab` to expand it to `<div class="foo"></div>`.

I know I could change `auto_complete_selector`in my preference to include `text`, but that's just a solution *for me*. We wouldn't want to have a package that asks you to change your preferences, we'd want it to just work.

Would there be a way, in my syntax file, to have the autocomplete popup activate while still in the `text`scope and keeping both features (popup for autocomplete and the tab to expand)?

Comment: My first idea would be to just use `scope: text.blade source.blade`. However this does not seem to be a good style.

Comment: @r-stein yeah, no. I've also tried with `scope: text.blade, source.blade` to no avail :(

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/Medalink/laravel-blade) the repo, by chance?

Comment: @MattDo : that's the popular one, but no, I'm on [here](https://github.com/jbrooksuk/Sublime-Blade)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which is the best solution. It maybe makes sense that the default setting for `auto_complete_selector` doesn't work in the `text` scope, but I don't understand why it's not working in `text.html`. Anyway, the way I see it, you have two options, each of them having their cons.

1. Don't mess with the user's setting, but communicate the need to adjust the `auto_complete_selector`, e.g. by using the [Messaging](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/messaging) system provided by Package Control. Con: users might ignore READMEs or install messages.
2. Override the user's setting by including a `.sublime-settings` that adds `text.blade` to the `auto_complete_selector` (I've seen [packages](https://bitbucket.org/klorenz/sublimerestructuredtextimproved/src) doing just that!) Con: interferes with *user* settings.

On a side note, I'm wondering whether it wouldn't be more appropriate to use `text.html.blade` as a scope.

Comment: Thank you for those two avenues, I'll definitely consider them! ;-) Also, for `text.html.blade`, what would be the main avantages over `source.blade`? (And looking at the files, since I'm not the main contributior, seems the `text.html` gets pushed in the main contexts section. That's probably the same as declaring it first in the file I guess!)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Blade, but from a brief look at it, I was under the impression that it looks a lot like HTML. So, wouldn't users appreciate if they could use all other completions that work in the `text.html` scope?

Comment: Absolutely. But yeah, they're pushed later on in the syntax files ;)